# jsp upload .vcf file to read mobile numbers

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, filereader

How to read .vcf file in jsp or how to pass .vcf file from html to controller.
I am using spring mvc.I want to read contacts from .vcf.
My jsp code:

```
<span><input type="file" id="vcfFile" name="vcfFile" /> </span>
```

jquery code :

```
$("#vcfUpload").click(function (){
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = function(){
                         $
                            .ajax({
                                url : "../acquaintance/readingContactsFromVcfFile?vcfFileData="+reader,
                                type : "post",
                                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                cache : false,
                                dataType : "json",
                                success : function(data) {
                                alert(data.message);
                                }
                            });
                        };
                        reader.readAsText(document.getElementById('vcfFile').files[0]);
                    });
```

controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/readingContactsFromVcfFile" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
ModelMap readContactsFromVcfFile(@RequestParam(value = "vcfFileData")Object vcfData) throws UserServiceException {
    log.info("vcf file reading"+ vcfData);
    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    try {
        List<VCard> Vcards = Ezvcard.parseHtml((String) vcfData).all();
        for (VCard vcard : Vcards) {
            log.info("name"+vcard.getFormattedName().getValue());
            }
        modelMap.addAttribute("message","success");
    } catch (Exception IoExp) {
        log.info("exception while reading contacts from vcf file",IoExp);
        modelMap.addAttribute("message","failed");
    }
    return modelMap;
}
```

And i am using Vcard for external :https://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard/wiki/Examples#Example_1.1:_Reading_from_a_plain-text_vCard

Comment: You need to explain the issue.  Are you having trouble sending the file via Ajax or reading it in Java? What kind of errors do you get? etc. As far as the Ajax side, you would *not* deal with it differently than any other file format, so search the various questions on SO that relate to uploading a file via Ajax.

Comment: when I execute the above program its showing vcf file reading[FileReader Object] in log ie in server,then its showing alert box with message success.Its not parsing the object vcfData. My requirement is to get list of contact ie the names in vcf file